# compare pointer to byte in C++ (Arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino, type-conversion

I'm playing with Arduino and I want to compare the string coming from a MQTT message.

This is my code to catch the incoming messages:

```
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  int i=0;
  for (i=0;i<length;i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

Serial.println((char)payload[0]);

  if(topic==topic_conmutador){
    if(strcmp((char*)(payload[0]), "0")==0)
    digitalWrite(built_in_PIN, LOW);
  }

}
```

The line `if(strcmp((char*)(payload[0]), "0")==0){` is giving me this error message:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'byte {aka unsigned char}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want to check if the first character of the incoming message is a 0.

Comment: Read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282)

Comment: `topic==topic_conmutador` this is wrong unless you are comparing pointers

Comment: Comparing a byte to a pointer makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want:

```
if (payload[0] == '0')
```

This is comparing the first character of the string `payload` to a character `'0'`.

*Note: `"0"` is string type with one character and `'0'` is char type.*